# How to stop annoying red Atom notifications when compiling Elm code

Tags: atom-editor, elm, elm-make

[image]

I've seen this issue for other languages too - for example here:
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8152 - and the solution was to just stop all notifications.

I actually want to stop only the notifications from elm-linter or whatever linter package is causing this.

My installed Atom packages are:

```
atom-beaufify               ---- first group
language-elm
linter
linter-elm-make
linter-ui-default

elmjutsu
elm-instant
busy-signal
intentions
```

Not sure which one of this is causing the issue - I checked all of them in settings and I didn't find any obvious way to turn notifications off.

I think that the package causing this is among the first group because are more likely to interact with the elm linting and notifications. 
Although I can't be sure.

Any insight on what package is causing this - or how to turn notifications off when linting is very appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I found the package that causes this problem. Is `atom-beautify` - there is no horizontal scrolling in `stack trace` - inside the red box - so this is why I didn't see it in full length previously.

```
I am looking for one of the following things:    

    a closing bracket '}'    
    whitespace    

at file:///C:/Users/devel/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:322:27    
at tryCatcher (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)   
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)    
at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)    
at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)    
at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)    
at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)    
at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)    
at Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\devel\.atom\packages\atom-beautify\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)    
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reinstalled again all elm-related packages including `atom-beautifier`.

**The error is gone for now** - although i can't say for sure - because previously it was gone also - and it appeared again. I can't replicate or predict why is behaving this way.

If you have an explanation please post another answer and i will choose it as the accepted answer.

Until then the re-installation of packages and restarting the editor works - until it doesn't - and you need to do it all over again..